# Perl Can't use string as a symbol ref while strict refs

Tags: perl

I need some guidance with the following Perl code. When I leave the `no strict 'refs'`, the `sub` works fine. But if the `no strict 'refs'` is removed, then I get the error message:

```
Can't use string ("A") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl
```

It dies in the lines marked as *"Here"* below. This `sub` needs to open (write >) all files from A..Z and based on the `regex` from the READ file (LOG) the output will be written to the correspond file output.

```
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;
no strict 'refs';  
...
...
sub file_split {

    my ( $i, $fh, @FH );
    my ( $file ) = @_;
    my ( @alpha) = ("A".."Z");

    for ( @alpha) {                            
            $fh = $_ ;
            open ( $fh,">","$_-$file" )  || die $!;      <--------- HERE
            push @FH, $fh;
    }

    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( {  binary => 1,
                                    allow_whitespace => 1,
                                    allow_loose_escapes => 1,
                                    allow_loose_quotes =>1,
                                    escape_char => undef ,
                                    sep_char => ',',
                                    auto_diag=> 1
                                    } );
    open( LOG,"<", $file ) || die $!;
    while ( my $row = $csv->getline( *LOG ) ) {
            if ( $row->[0] =~ /^(\w)/ ) {
                    print $1                       <--------- HERE
                            "$row->[0]".",".
                            "$row->[1]" .",".
                            "$row->[2]" .",".
                            "$row->[3]" .",".
                            "$row->[4]".",".
                            "$row->[5]"."\n";

            } else {
                        print "Record skipped... --> $row->[0] <-- ... please verify     \n";
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't assign `$fh = $_` it's not doing anything useful.

`@FH` should be `%FH` and instead of the `push` try:

```
$FH{ $_ } = $fh
```

Replace the `$1` with `$FH{ $1 }`.

Comment: That did the trick. And print $1 was replaced to print {$FH{$1}} . Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You're asking perl to use the value of $fh as the name of the filehandle here:

```
for ( @alpha) {                            
            $fh = $_ ;
            open ( $fh,">","$_-$file" )  || die $!;      <--------- HERE
            push @FH, $fh;
    }
```

You should instead consider using a lexical variable and having that autovivified into a filehandle by open, then store this in a hash to get at it later:

```
for ( @alpha) {                            
            open ( my $fh,">","$_-$file" )  || die $!;
            $handles{$_} =  $fh;
}
```

so that you can use it later here:

```
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( *LOG ) ) {
            if ( $row->[0] =~ /^(\w)/ ) {
                    print $handles{$1}                       <--------- HERE
                            ...
```

Comment: This works. Just the print $handles{$1} had to be replaced to print {$handles{$1}}  . Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use a string literal as a filehandle:  in your `foreach` loop, `$_` takes on the values `"A"`,`"B"`,etc.  So, don't do that.  Just make a new filehandle and push that onto `@FH`.