# perl + read multiple csv files + manipulate files + provide output_files + syntax error symbol ref

Tags: perl

Buiding on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493405/perl-read-multiple-csv-files-manipulate-files-provide-output-files/22493537?noredirect=1#comment34412209_22493537). I am still having syntax trouble with this script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;   # this is used for the multiple files part...

#START::Getting current working directory 
use Cwd qw();
my $source_dir = Cwd::cwd();
#END::Getting current working directory 

print "source dir -> $source_dir\n";
my $output_prefix = 'format_';

#print "dh -> $dh\n";
opendir my $dh, $source_dir; #Changing this to work on current directory; changing back
                                # added the "()" here ($dh) as otherwise an error
for my $file (readdir($dh)) {
    next if $file !~ /\.csv$/;
    next if $file =~ /^\Q$output_prefix\E/;

    my $orig_file = "$source_dir/$file";
    my $format_file = "$source_dir/$output_prefix$file";

    # .... old processing code here ...
    ## Start:: This part works on one file edited for this script ##
    #open my $orig_fh,   '<', 'orig.csv'   or die $!; #line 14 and 15 above already do this!!
    #open my $format_fh, '>', 'format.csv' or die $!;
    print "format_file-> $format_file\n";
    #print $format_fh scalar <$orig_fh>; # Copy header line #orig needs changeing
    print {$format_file}  scalar <$orig_file>; # Copy header line

    my %data;
    my @labels;

    #while (<$orig_fh>) { #orig needs changing
    while (<$orig_file>) {
      chomp;
      my @fields = split /,/, $_, -1;
      my ($label, $max_val) = @fields[1,12];
      if ( exists $data{$label} ) {
        my $prev_max_val = $data{$label}[12] || 0;
        $data{$label} = \@fields if $max_val and $max_val > $prev_max_val;
      }
      else {
        $data{$label} = \@fields;
        push @labels, $label;
      }
    }

    for my $label (@labels) {
      #print $format_fh join(',', @{ $data{$label} }), "\n";  #orig needs changing
      print $format_file join(',', @{ $data{$label} }), "\n";
    }
    ## END:: This part works on one file edited for this script ##

}
```

I can fix this line `opendir my $dh, $source_dir;` by adding brackets `($dh)`

but i am still having trouble with this line `print {$format_file}  scalar <$orig_file>; # Copy header line` line

I get the following error:

```
Can't use string ("/home/Kevin Smith/Perl/format_or"...) as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at formatfile_QforStackOverflow.pl line 29.
```

Can anyone advise?

I have tried using advise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356653/perl-cant-use-string-as-a-symbol-ref-while-strict-refs) but there is not much joy.

Comment: I don't want bugging you too much ;), - this is 3rd part of your work. My advice is - try break your code into smaller, more manageable subroutines. Debug each sub alone. This way, it is much-much easier get a right results. For example, it is easy to read something like: `convert_csv($_) for (@files);` and the `convert_csv` is sub for converting ONE file. etc...etc... Small subs, easy debug, more manageable, shorter questions, faster a more precise answers :)

Comment: @jm666 tks and agree but slowly learning at this stage...

Answer (score 1):

Use `print $format_file ...` or `print ${format_file} ...`

However `$format_file` is just a string containing the name of the file, not a filehandle. You have to open the file:

```
open my $format_fh, '>', $format_file or die $!;
...
print $format_$fh ... ;
```